# I can't log in to elastic search using java with 302 response but it worked with postman

Tags: java, elasticsearch, webclient

Actually, I want to visit the ElasticSearch directly without kibana. I use Java to design this process. When I used postman to test the login step with token and `kbn-xsrf` in the headers (picture showed here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi0JI.pngstrong): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti9Nf.png)
[image]
, I can get the result from postman.
However, when I used Java to design this process, it failed with 302. I tried `RequestEntity` method and `WebClient` methods, both of them failed (picture showed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi0JI.pngstrong)). Anyone could help to solve this issue, big thanks.

```
package com.sap.ngom.collection.client;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.cloudfoundry.uaa.tokens.AbstractToken;
import org.cloudfoundry.uaa.tokens.GetTokenByPasswordResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.RequestEntity;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


@Service
public class ElasticSearchClient {

    private static final String CF_TOKEN_URL = "https://uaa.cf.us10.hana.ondemand.com";
    private static final String CF_LOGS_URL = "https://logs.cf.us10.hana.ondemand.com";
    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String username = System.getenv("USER");
    String password = System.getenv("PWD");
    String token = "";

    @Autowired
    private RestOperations restOperations;

    public JsonNode getLogsByElasticSearch() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{

        String query = mapper.readValue(new File(getFileURI("/query.json")), JsonNode.class).toString();
        String index = mapper.readValue(new File(getFileURI("/index.json")), JsonNode.class).toString();        
        String queryBody = index + "\n" + query + "\n" + index + "\n" + query;      

        ResponseEntity responseEntity = retrieveLog(queryBody);

        if (responseEntity.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.FOUND){

            dealWithRedirect(responseEntity);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void dealWithRedirect(ResponseEntity responseEntity){
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = responseEntity.getHeaders();
        String loction = responseHeaders.get("Location").toString();
        String loginUrl = loction.substring(1, loction.length()-1);

        String setCookie = responseHeaders.get("Set-Cookie").toString();
        setCookie = setCookie.substring(1, loction.length()-1);

        HttpHeaders loginHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        loginHeaders.set("Cookie", setCookie);
        loginHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic Y2Y6");
        loginHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED); 

        String body = "grant_type=password&username=jane.wang03@sap.com&password="+ System.getenv("PWD") + "&response_type=user_token";

        RequestEntity<String> loginRequestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(body, loginHeaders, HttpMethod.POST, URI.create(loginUrl));
        ResponseEntity loginResponse = restOperations.exchange(loginRequestEntity, Object.class);

        String temp = "";
    }

    private void passAuthentication(String state){
        String url = CF_TOKEN_URL + "/oauth/authorize?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=sleeve-app-logs&response_type=code&state=" + state;

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "bearer " + token);

        RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(headers, HttpMethod.GET, URI.create(url));

        HttpStatus responseEntity = restOperations.exchange(requestEntity, Object.class).getStatusCode();        
    }


    private ResponseEntity retrieveLog(String queryBody){

        if (token == ""){
            token = getToken();
        }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "bearer " + token);
        headers.set("kbn-xsrf", "reporting");  

        String url = CF_LOGS_URL + "/elasticsearch/_msearch";
        RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(queryBody, headers, HttpMethod.POST, URI.create(url));
        ResponseEntity responseEntity = restOperations.exchange(requestEntity, Object.class);

        return responseEntity;
    }


    private String getToken() {

        String body = "grant_type=password";
        try {
            body += "&username=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
            body += "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            body += "&response_type=user_token";
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic Y2Y6");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);       

        RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(body, headers, HttpMethod.POST, URI.create(CF_TOKEN_URL + "/oauth/token"));
        ResponseEntity<GetTokenByPasswordResponse> responseEntity = restOperations.exchange(requestEntity, GetTokenByPasswordResponse.class);
        AbstractToken token = responseEntity.getBody();              

        return token.getAccessToken();
    }


    private URI getFileURI(String path) {        
        URL ruleURL = ElasticSearchClient.class.getResource(path);
        URI uri = null;

        try {
            uri = ruleURL.toURI();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put a code snippet of you java code here?

Comment: your code looks fine, But I suggest to debug the issue from bottom up, in other words, try to hard code your token, query body, and other values and replace them one by one till you find the cause

Comment: already debug and use the hard code token, still doesn't work. i tried javascript, it works. it is very strange.